# R Stringr, how to replace part of a string, which varies in length?

Tags: r, token, sentiment-analysis, stringr

I am trying to do a sentiment analysis of some tweets, and I need to use the lexicon to "translate" the emoji code into an emotion.

The data looks like this:

```
ID;tweet
1;Btc y<c4><b1>l<c4><b1>n en y<c3><bc> yes yes
2;Top Cryptos:  BTC 13756.50$ | 11449.53<e2><82><ac> going up
3;8. Galileo'nun d<c3><bc>nya good dedi<c4><9f>i i
4;New arrival! Thanks @afilini <e2><9d><a4> #mastering
5;<e2><ad><90><ef><b8><8f><e2><ad><90><ef>
```

The lexicon looks like this:

```
ID;emoji;emotion
1;<c4><b1>;glad
2;<c3><bc>;angry
3;<e2><82><ac>;thrilled
4;<c4><9f>;cry
5;<e2><9d><a4>;suspecious
6;<e2><ad><90><ef><b8>;happy
7;<8f><e2>;no
8;<ad><90><ef>;funny
```

Would it be possible to use the lexicon to replace the emoji code with the emotion?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use the `mgsub()` function from the `mgsub` package and then add the new column via `dplyr::mutate()` as follows.

Let

```
df <- data.frame(tweet = c("Btc y<c4><b1>l<c4><b1>n en y<c3><bc> yes yes", 
                           "Top Cryptos:  BTC 13756.50$  11449.53<e2><82><ac> going up"))
lexicon <- data.frame(emoji = c("<c4><b1>", "<c3><bc>", 
                                "<e2><82><ac>"), 
                      emotion = c("glad", "angry", "thrilled"))
```

be your tweet and lexicon data.

Then the line

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(new = mgsub::mgsub(., lexicon$emoji, lexicon$emotion))
```

has the desired

**Output**

```
> df2
                                                       tweet                                                  tweet
1               Btc y<c4><b1>l<c4><b1>n en y<c3><bc> yes yes                      Btc ygladlgladn en yangry yes yes
2 Top Cryptos:  BTC 13756.50$  11449.53<e2><82><ac> going up Top Cryptos:  BTC 13756.50$  11449.53thrilled going up
```